# How do I set a value for HttpResponseMessage.Content in C#

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse, http-get

I have a Web API method that returns data in the `HttpResponseMessage.Content` property. Here is the code for the method:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage MethodName()
{
    try
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent("Hello WORLD", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        response.Content = new StringContent("{\"error\": \"" + ex.Message + "\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return response;
    }
}
```

When I call this method from Postman, the response metadata shows that the response has a length of 11, which is correct for the "Hello WORLD" string. However, I cannot see the actual data in the response body.

What am I missing?

Here is the response:

```json
{
    "version": "1.1",
    "content": {
        "headers": [
            {
                "key": "Content-Type",
                "value": [
                    "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                ]
            },
            {
                "key": "Content-Length",
                "value": [
                    "11"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "statusCode": 200,
    "reasonPhrase": "OK",
    "headers": [],
    "trailingHeaders": [],
    "requestMessage": null,
    "isSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

Comment: _Here's a possible rephrased version of your question that you can post on Stack Overflow_ - strong smell of ChatGPT

Comment: @stuartd yes I forgot to remove that bit.. nothing wrong with it helping me post a question is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would use [`IActionResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-7.0) as a return type of your method then you could take advantage of `Ok` and `StatusCode` methods of the base class. Your method could be rewritten like this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult MethodName()
{
    try
    {
        return Ok("Hello WORLD");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "{\"error\": \"" + ex.Message + "\"}") ;
    }
}
```

Quite frankly I don't trully understand the sole purpose of your `try`-`catch` block but I hope you get the point.

---

**UPDATE #1**

> why I can't set `HttpResponseMessage.Content` correctly.

The `StringContent` does have a [single property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent?view=net-7.0#properties) called `Headers`. In other words the value is not exposed as a property. The popular serializers (like Json.NET or System.Text.Json) serializes only the properties by default.

If you could use [`JsonContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.jsoncontent?view=net-8.0) instead of `StringContent` then the serialization will work correctly since it is exposing the [`Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.jsoncontent.value?view=net-8.0) as property.

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = JsonContent.Create("Hello WORLD");   
var responseInJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented);
responseInJson.Dump();
```

```json
{
   "Version":"1.1",
   "Content":{
      "ObjectType":"System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
      "Value":"Hello WORLD",
      "Headers":[
         {
            "Key":"Content-Type",
            "Value":[
               "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "StatusCode":200,
   "ReasonPhrase":"OK",
   "Headers":[
      
   ],
   "TrailingHeaders":[
      
   ],
   "RequestMessage":null,
   "IsSuccessStatusCode":true
}
```

Related dotnet fiddle link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NiM8lx

Comment: The try catch is becuase the code has been simplified for the purpose of creating this question.  I have some logic and then try and set the HttpResponseMessage.Content value. - but what ever I try to set it to never ends up in the object.

Comment: @AyoAdesina Okay, the try-catch now it makes sense. Did my proposed solution work for you?

Comment: Your solution is a work around. - and I am using it already in my project. - It is another way to do it, but it doesn't actually answer my question of why I can't set HttpResponseMessage.Content correctly. - Ill vote your solution up, but I am still unsure why I can't set HttpResponseMessage.Content. Might be something else like .net version, API project version or something.

Comment: @AyoAdesina I've updated my post, could you please check it?

Comment: That makes perfect sense... thanks